# Как объединить повторяющиеся строки в таблице с условием?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть процедура, которая находит дубликаты по полю:

```
WITH DuplicateValue
AS (
    SELECT task.Code
        ,COUNT(*) AS CNT
        FROM dbo.TaskData AS task
    GROUP BY task.Code
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
SELECT
    ,task.Code
    ,task.Power
    ,task.Process
    ,task.Order
    ,task.Name
FROM dbo.TaskData AS task
WHERE task.Code IN (
        SELECT task
        FROM DuplicateValue
        )
ORDER BY task.Code;
```

Так я получаю все записи, где поле `Code` повторяется. 
Нужно собрать все строки с одним `task.Code` в одну по такому параметру:

```
row_one:
    Code = 235
    Power = 12
    Process = 0
    Order = 999
    Name = N'Что-то'  

row_two:
    Code = 235
    Power = 0
    Process = 231
    Order = 0
    Name = N'Что-то'

procedure_result_row:
    Code = 235
    Power = 12
    Process = 231
    Order = 999
    Name = N'Что-то'
```

То есть, если значение `NULL` или `0`, то оно заменяется на значение из записи с тем же `Code`, где значение не `NULL` или `0`. В итоге получается одна строка. 
Повтором по `Сode` может быть и 3 и 4 (в теории и 10).

Собирался как то через `while` цикл перебирать одну за одной записи, соединять их и по одной вставлять в таблицу. Но не уверен, что это хорошее решение.
Если использовать `while`,то с каждой итерацией нужно смотреть дубликаты к итерируемой записи, а это отдельный запрос (записей в таблице > 50к).

Может есть более "правильный" способ?

Comment: Если не важно какой из 3,4..10, то по-моему тут достаточно `select Code, max(Power), ..., max(Name) from TaskData group by Code`. Либо `max(nullif(Power, 0))` вместо `max(Power)` (смотря какие данные), и т.п. Это если просто выборку делать. Если потом дубликаты удалять, то чуть посложнее будет запрос.

Comment: *если значение NULL или 0, то оно заменяется на значение из записи с тем же Code, где значение не NULL или 0. В итоге получается одна строка.* А если оба не NULL и не ноль, и при этом неравные?

Comment: @Akina тогда нужно добавить такие записи в отдельную таблицу

Comment: @i-one спасибо. Вроде как надо работает, но пугает, что слишком просто выглядит). Может вы добавите от в ответ? Ну, чтобы + к репутации был и так далее?

Comment: @nomatter, добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я приведу сокращённый пример.

Пусть есть данные

```
DECLARE @TaskData TABLE([Code] int, [Power] int);
INSERT INTO @TaskData
VALUES (235, NULL), (235, 0), (235, 12), (235, 12);
```

Исходя из условий, вот такой запрос вернёт данные без дубликатов

```
SELECT
    t.[Code],
    MAX(t.[Power]) AS [Power]
FROM @TaskData t
GROUP BY t.[Code];
```

Если же нужно не просто получить эти данные, а убрать дубликаты в исходной таблице, то можно это сделать за два шага.

Первый шаг

```
WITH NormalizedData AS (
    SELECT
        [Power],
        [New_Power] = MAX(t.[Power]) OVER (PARTITION BY t.[Code])
    FROM @TaskData t
)
UPDATE NormalizedData
SET
    [Power] = [New_Power];
```

сделает все дубликаты для одного `[Code]` одинаковыми и "правильными".

Второй шаг

```
WITH NormalizedData AS (
    SELECT
        [RowNum] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.[Code] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM @TaskData t
)
DELETE FROM NormalizedData
WHERE RowNum > 1;
```

удалит дубликаты для тех строк, у которых они есть.

Если в данных могут быть отрицательные `[Power]`, то, чтобы условие *"не NULL или 0"* выполнялось, вместо `MAX(t.[Power])` нужно использовать `MAX(NULLIF(t.[Power], 0))`.

Сравните, например, результат такого запроса

```
SELECT MAX(t.[Power])
FROM (VALUES (NULL), (0), (-1)) t([Power]);
```

и такого

```
SELECT MAX(NULLIF(t.[Power], 0))
FROM (VALUES (NULL), (0), (-1)) t([Power]);
```

Comment: А в запросе такого вида можно использовать `join`? У меня есть еще одна таблица (дубликатов нет) , где есть совпадения по `Code` с таблицей `TaskData `(где есть дубликаты). `inner join`ном пытаюсь приконектить по `Code`, но получаю  _Column 'dbo.QueryData.Code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause._. То-есть хочу увидеть поля из `QueryData` и `TaskData`. Но, чтобы данные в `TaskData` были нормализованы(нули заменены в смысле). Или нужно сначала создать нормализованную таблицу, а потом `QueryData` конектить?

Comment: @nomatter, да, можно сделать join c результатом группированного select-а, что-то типа `select ... from (select code, max(power), ... from TableData group by code) tn join QueryData qd on qd.Code = tn.Code`